# Windows Error 10061 - Django Channels

Tags: python, django, redis, chat, channel

There is a problem when using Django Channels In some Windows 10 machines. 
Basically i can not connect to the Socket [Error 10061]  and python gives me out an error

```
ERROR - server - Exception inside application: Multiple exceptions: [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('::1', 6379), [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('127. 0.0.1', 6379)
```

I know it's Windows/OS level problem.
I have already turned off all firewalls etc. Still cant connect to the socket

Example repo: https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have fixed the problem, however still don't know the root cause.

My solution was:

> 1) Install Redis windows build https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads
>
> 2) Reboot PC
>
> 3) pip install pypiwin32
>
> 4) run project

Even works after turning on all firewalls